# How to call Intent in a static parameterized method and start new activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to call Intent in a static parameterized method and wants to start new activity from there. I'm using a mathod call named as **zodiacSign** in my **MainActivity** with two parameters, it works and throw a call to another activity **HoroscopeFinder**. During its working I want to open a new activity form HoroscopeFinder.
If someone knows please help.
my code is given below:

*MainActivity Code*

```
 dateSetListener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            //code
            month=month+1;
            String date= dayOfMonth+"/"+month+"/"+year;
            datePicker.setText(date);
            //from here we can get day and month
            String getDay= String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
            getDayInt=Integer.parseInt(getDay);
            String getMonth= String.valueOf(month);
            getMonthInt=Integer.parseInt(getMonth);
            //method call for deduct sign using DOB
            zodiacSign(getDayInt, getMonthInt);}
```

*HoroscopeFinder class code*

```
public class HoroscopeFinder {

static String astroSign="";

public static void zodiacSign(int day, int month)
{
    //Toast.makeText(, "here done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //Log.i("check", "done here...!");


    if ((month == 12 && day >= 22 && day <= 31) || (month ==  1 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
        astroSign="Capricorn";
    }
    else if ((month ==  1 && day >= 20 && day <= 31) || (month ==  2 && day >= 1 && day <= 17)) {
        astroSign="Aquarius";
        //astro_sign="Aquarius";
    }
    else if ((month ==  2 && day >= 18 && day <= 29) || (month ==  3 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
        astroSign="Pisces";
    }
    else ((month ==  3 && day >= 20 && day <= 31) || (month ==  4 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
        astroSign="Aries";
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, AriesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your zodiacSign method as

```
   ........
   ........
   public static void zodiacSign(int day, int month, Context c)
   {
    if (...) {
        ....
        ...

        Intent intent=new Intent(c, AriesActivity.class);
        c.startActivity(intent);
       }
    }
```

And then in MainActivity pass `context` to your zodiacSign method as

```
... zodiacSign(getDayInt, getMonthInt, MainActivity.this); // this context will help you there to start a new activity
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an `Activity` to `zodiacSign` so it can construct and start the intent:

```
public static void zodiacSign(int day, int month, Activity activity)
{
    if (...) {

        ...

        Intent intent=new Intent(activity, AriesActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Then, back in your `MainActivity` class:

```
...
zodiacSign(getDayInt, getMonthInt, MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: I think you only need a Context. You do not need an activity.

Comment: @doubleA - True, but then if it's passed a `Context` that is not an `Activity`, then the intent must include the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` launch flag and the activity will run in a new task. If you really want to accept any `Context`, you need to account for that possibility.

Comment: @doubleA i got your point but still didn't know How and which context i would have to pass in my function call?

Comment: @IrfanAkram - Pass the activity that is calling the `zodiacSign` method. The effect would be the same as if you called `startActivity()` from the main activity itself.

Comment: @IrfanAkram check out second answer. It is as intended.